# Adding conditions to Containable in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, recursion, cakephp-2.0, conditional-statements, containable

Previously I was relying on recursive, but I didn't get solution for some, then I found that Containable works fine for these.

I am developing a movie review website. In that I need to show the list of movies which is related to a particular Genre.

I have this below code:

```
//example
$genre = "drama";

$options = array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Movie',
        'MoveiGenre.Genre' => array(
            'conditions' => array('MovieGenre.Genre.name = "'.$genre.'"')
        ),
        'MovieGenre.Genre.name'
    ),
    'recursive' => 2,
    'limit' => 10
);
$this->paginate = $options;
$this->set('movies',$this->paginate());
```

The real problem starts here, I get all the movies, even if its not related to the genre "drama".
Where am I going wrong ?

Let me explain the database table:

Table: movies

```
 ----------------------------
 | id | title | description |
 ----------------------------
 | 1  | mov1  | something1  |
 | 2  | mov2  | something2  |
 | 3  | mov3  | something3  |
 ----------------------------
```

Table: genres

```
 ---------------
 | id | name   |
 ---------------
 | 1  | drama  |
 | 2  | sci-fi |
 | 3  | comedy |
 ---------------
```

Table: movie_genres

```
 -------------------------------
 | id | movie_id | genre_id    |
 -------------------------------
 | 1  | 1        | 1           |
 | 2  | 1        | 2           |
 | 3  | 2        | 2           |
 -------------------------------
```

Here you can see that one movie_id has multiple genre_id. I should get only `mov1` but I'm getting both movies in an array.

~~ **EDIT** ~~
oops!!
sorry forgot to mention, I'm using this code in `MoviesController`. All 3 table has respective controller. So pls suggest me in which controller I can use.

**EDIT:2**

```
class Movie extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'title';

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public $hasMany = array(
        'MovieGenre' => array(
            'className' => 'MovieGenre',
            'foreignKey' => 'movie_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'MovieLanguage' => array(
            'className' => 'MovieLanguage',
            'foreignKey' => 'movie_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
    );

}
```

Model: Genre

```
class Genre extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'name';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Movie' => array(
            'className' => 'Movie',
            'joinTable' => 'movie_genres',
            'foreignKey' => 'genre_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'movie_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

Model: MovieGenre

```
class MovieGenre extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Movie' => array(
            'className' => 'Movie',
            'foreignKey' => 'movie_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Genre' => array(
            'className' => 'Genre',
            'foreignKey' => 'genre_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TLDR:** do your find on Genre and contain it's Movies, or use joins() - doing your search on Movies and containing Genre with conditions won't work for the results you want.

---

**Explanation:**

Below is your corrected 'contain' code, but more importantly, doing a 'contain' on Genre won't return the results you're looking for.

What it does - limits the contained genres based on your condition... so it will pull ALL movies, and contain the genres that match `$genre`.

---

**Solutions (depending on your needs):**

*Solution 1)*

- Do a `find()` on Genre, with the condition, and contain it's movies.  This will pull the genre that matches, then only the movies that are related to it.

*Solution 2)* - the one I'd recommend

- Use 'joins()':

---

```
$conditions = array();
$conditions['joins'] = array(
    array(
        'table' => 'genres_movies', //or movie_genres if you've specified it as the table to use
        'alias' => 'GenresMovie',
        'type' => 'INNER'
        'conditions' => array(
            'GenresMovie.movie_id = Movie.id'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'table' => 'genres',
        'alias' => 'Genre',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Genre.id = GenresMovie.genre_id',
            'Genre.name = "' . $genre . '"'
        )
    )
);
$this->Movie->find('all', $conditions);
```

---

**Your edited (corrected imo) 'contain' example**

```
//edited example
$genre = "drama";

$options = array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Genre' => array(
            'conditions' => array('Genre.name' => $genre)
        )
    ),
    'recursive' => -1,
    'limit' => 10
);
$this->paginate = $options;
$this->set('movies', $this->paginate('Movie'));
```

1. you don't "contain" the model you're doing the find on (ie I removed 'Movie' from your contain array).
2. you only contain models, not things like "MovieGenre.Genre" (I can't think of any time  you would use '.' concatenated models)
3. recursive needs to be -1 to use Containable - you should set this to -1 in the AppModel and forget the concept of recursive - it's bad

Comment: Awesome bro, The joins working perfectly. Can you suggest some advanced book for cakephp. I couldn't any such book. `Thanks A Lot :)` works perfect, you miss some of the `'` quotes :P

Comment: Very glad it helped / worked.  Fixed the quotes (looks like you tried to too - ty).

Comment: I'm curious why you prefer to use joins over contain?

Comment: @SelaYair - I don't believe I said anything about preferring joins.  In this particular case (as listed in the answer), they either need to use joins or change which model they query from.  Option1, Options2.  No preference.